Image uploading issue in Azure Blob storage using SAS token
I’m working on a critical issue regarding image uploading in Azure blob storage using SAS token API.
While testing the functionality via Postman, we've observed that the image upload process is successful, yielding a status code of 201. However, when attempting the same operation from within our application, although we receive a status code of 201, the image fails to load.
  Future<void> uploadImageToAzure() async {
    await getUploadTokenAPi();
    final image = await _signaturePadKey.currentState!.toImage();
    final byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
    setState(() {

    });
    bytes = byteData?.buffer.asUint8List(byteData.offsetInBytes,byteData.lengthInBytes);
    setState(() {});
    var headers = {
      'x-ms-blob-content-type': 'image/png',
      'x-ms-blob-type': 'BlockBlob',
      'Content-type': 'application/octet-stream',
      'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
      'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    };

    Dio dio = Dio();
    // log("${base64Encode(bytes!)}");
    Response response = await dio.put(
      uploadtokenResponce.data["token"],
      data: base64Encode(bytes!),
      options: Options(
        headers: headers,
      ),
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 201) {
      print("================");
      log(json.encode(response.headers.map));
      print("================");
      log("Data : ${response.statusCode}");
    } else {
      print(response.statusMessage);
    }
    try {} catch (e) {
      print('Error uploading image: $e');
    }
  }

_signaturePadKey = this key use for take signature image

Edit the question with full error message?

Have you tried with different image?

yes @Venkatesan, i always trie new image. because this feature base on signature pad. also please check my header is perfect or not

Try with Content-Type : image/png only don't use x-ms-blob-content-type.

@Venkatesan, Not worked

I think error you are passing the image in may be in wrong method because for me also working in postman.

I passing as base64 string and also check base64 string online on base64 compiler so base64 data is currect. any other method to upload image using sas token

The reason you are not able to view the image is because you are uploading the data in base64 format. What you need to do is upload the data in binary format.
Please try something like (untested code):
Response response = await dio.put(
      uploadtokenResponce.data["token"],
      data: bytes!,
      options: Options(
        headers: headers,
      ),
    );


this is not working. postman request working fine but we are upload via mobile app is problem. You are expert in azure blob storage. any see mistake on my api request.

Please make sure that you’re uploading binary data. Also, please share how you’re accessing the blob. Directly via URL or downloading it in memory?

I'm passing binary data as you said. currently we uploading image via mobile app and testing for load image in google chrome.
